# How to add "ca.uwaterloo.gp.fmp_0.6.6" plugin to eclipse 3.7.1 and use it to edit Feature Models

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin

I am having eclipse 3.7.1 and a plugin to edit FMP (Feature Modelling Project) . How to add this plugin and edit `.fmp` files

`Plugin name : ca.uwaterloo.gp.fmp_0.6.6.jar`

**Site:** http://gp.uwaterloo.ca/fmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no update site for this plugin.  You can take the jar file and drop it into your eclipse/dropins folder.  This should work, but is less than ideal since it doesn't really use Eclipse's provisioning system.

If this doesn't work for you then you should contact the authors of the plugin and ask them to create a proper update site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir.. I copied the jar file into the dropins folder but, I am unable to detect any changes in the Eclipse IDE, where i can find the plugin usage in the IDE.. the IDE remains same..

Comment: If you have PDE tools installed in your Eclipse, then you can open the Plugin Registry view and look for the plugin you just installed in the list..  Also, take a look at the error log.  Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log.